# ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans'

Tags: json, python-2.7, compiler-errors

here is my code. Not only in this code, in every code where i am importing any module, ImportError: cannot import name 'package name' shows up

```
from string import maketrans

str = "geeksforgeeks"

str1 = "gfo"
str2 = "abc"

# using maktrans() to map elements of str2 with str1
mapped = maketrans(str1, str2);

# using translate() to translate using the mapping
print"The string after translation using mapped elements is : "
printstr.translate(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be

```
print str.translate(mapped)
```

not

```
printstr.translate(mapped);
```

Could you run this command in terminal and post the output

```
which -a python
```